# PyInstaller 3.2, how to "bundle" arguments?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, web.py

I'm using PyInstaller 3.2 to package a Web.py app. Typically, with Web.py and the built-in WSGI [server](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ssl), you specify the port on the command line, like

```
$ python main.py 8091
```

Would run the Web.py app on port 8091 (default is 8080). I'm bundling the app with PyInstaller via a spec file, but I can't figure out how to specify the port number with that -- passing in Options only seems to work for the [3 given ones in the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html). I'm tried:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [('8091', None, 'OPTION')],
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything. I didn't see anything else in the docs -- is there another way to bundle / specify / include command-line arguments to the PyInstaller spec file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So very hacky, but what I wound up doing was to just append an argument in `sys.argv` in my web.py app...

```
sys.argv.append('8888')
app.run()
```

I also thought in my `spec` file I could just do:

```
a = Analysis(['main.py 8888'],
```

But that didn't work at all.

Answer (score -1):

`options` argument in EXE is only for the python interpreter ([ref](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#giving-run-time-python-options))